# Generic upperbound with List vs Array or Object

Tags: java, generics

I'm sorry if this has been asked somewhere else, but my search engine skills are failing me.

I thought I had an understanding on generics, but this is another thing that's throwing a wrench in my thought process. Why is T extends Comparable valid for class B which extends A for arrays and B objects, but not List

```java
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B[] values = new B[1];
        sort(values); // this is OK
        sort(new B()); // this is OK
        List<B> b = new ArrayList<>();
        sort(b); // not allowed
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] a) {

    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T a) {

    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<T> a) {

    }
}

class A implements Comparable<A> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(A a) {
        return 0;
    }
}

class B extends A {

}
```

Comment: Looks like problem with casting. `public static <T> void sort(List<T> a)` and `public static <T extends Comparable<A>> void sort(List<T> a)` should work

Comment: `B` implements indirectly `Comparable<A>` so that for the third `sort` variant neither `T=A` (`<A extends Comparable<A>> void sort(List<A> a)`, wrong parameter type) nor `T=B` (`B extends Comparable<B>` not fulfilled) work. For previous `sort` calls with single object or array, `T=A` works.

Comment: You should use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.

Comment: The point is that a `List<B>` is **not** a `List<A>`, even though `B : A`.

Answer (score 4):

Because `List<B>` is not a `subtype` of `List<A>` and you're using A's compareTo implementation.

So you need to add `? super` below

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> a) {

}
```

By taking `T` to be `B`, you get `B extends Comparable<? super B>`

This is valid since

1. `B extends Comparable<A>` and
2. `A super B`